# My Enable Tracing option in QGIS has stopped working

Tags: qgis, tracing

I am currently working on a project in QGIS and my Enable Tracing feature has become blurred out and wont work. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turn on the Snap tool**

The `Enable trace` option is part of the `Snap` tool. In your case the snap tool seems to be turned off.

Click the horse-shoe shaped red magnet on the left of the `Snap` toolbar to turn it on.

Comment: thank you very much!